# MasterSlider plugin strips anchor tags from URL - looking for the bug

Tags: javascript, wordpress

A WordPress webpage contains anchor tags where I want to be able to jump from links on other pages. It works fine without the MasterSlider plugin. But when the plugin is activated, its strips the #anchortag from the end of the URL, and therefore the page loads only at the top, not at the anchor tag.

I was looking for the solution on google and found a similar problem that was described and solved here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/anchor-link-to-an-anchor-tag-on-another-page-does-not-work

Similarly to Jessica's approach I was attempting to locate the code that strips the anchor tag, and found the most probable culprit to be in masterslider.min.js

Edit: the unminified version of that file masterslider.js can be found at: 
http://jsbin.com/patidituqu/edit?html,js,output
Found only 6 instances of '#' which may be relevant to the problem, but still don't know how to fix the bug.

Unfortunately my JavaScript knowledge is not sufficient to identify which code does the stripping. I would be very thankful if anybody could help find the bug. Otherwise I will have to get rid of the slider and use another one.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: if you think the culprit is that file use a code beautifier to make it readable, or see if there is an unminified version included with the plugin. then ctrl-f for '#' and see if anything comes up

Comment: @jopfre Thanks for the advice. I have found an unminified version, the masterslider.js which can be viewed at: 
http://jsbin.com/patidituqu/edit?html,js,output

Did the search for the '#' and there are only 11 matches out of which only 6 seems to be relevant the rest is in color code. Even most of those 6 are in comments. I still dont know how would I have to change the code to fix the bug and not to brake the functionality. Any suggestions? Thanks again.